# Spring Boot Upload Multipart 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I have such a method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ResponseBody
@PreAuthorize("@securityService.isAllowedAccessByCurrentUser(#resource?.userId)")
public Post createPost(@RequestPart(required = false) @Valid final MultipartFile media,
        @RequestPart(required = true) @Valid PostUploadDto resource, final UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder,
        final HttpServletResponse response) {
    return service.create(resource, media);
}
```

In application.properties I have this:

```
# fileupload
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1024MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=1024MB
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
```

When I try and upload a 1.2 MB file, I get 413 Request Entity Too Large

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is the React code that calls the API:

```
export const createNewPost = async (caption, userId, tokenData, imageURI, gameId) => {
  const resource = {
    userId,
    caption,
    hashtags: allTagsFrom(caption),
    mentions: allMentionsFrom(caption),
    gameId,
    createdOn: moment()
      .utc()
      .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
  };
  if (imageURI) {
    const { uri, type } = imageURI;
    const data = [
      {
        name: 'resource',
        type: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(resource),
      },
      {
        name: 'media',
        type,
        filename: 'media.jpg',
        data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(uri.substring(7)),
      },
    ];
    return RNFetchBlob.fetch(
      'POST',
      `${serverUrl}/post`,
      {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenData.access_token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
      data
    );
  } else {
    return RNFetchBlob.fetch(
      'POST',
      `${serverUrl}/post`,
      {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenData.access_token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
      [
        {
          name: 'resource',
          type: 'application/json',
          data: JSON.stringify(resource),
        },
      ]
    );
  }
};
```

It's interesting to note that I can succesfully make this call if the media is under a certain threshold, which is smaller than the one i set in the properties file

Comment: How are you doing your POST request? Can you show your HTML form?  Does your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: @PhilipWrage please see edit

Comment: I think you have it backwards. Your post request should Accept multipart form in your JavaScript and should not have a content-type specified

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli, it still doesn't explain why it works for smaller images but not "larger" images that are below 1024MB right?

Comment: My thought is that you are saying

Comment: Do you get the same results down both paths (imageURI vs. no imageURI)?

Comment: @PhilipWrage, if no image uri, never an issue, if image uri, sometimes an issue depending on size

Comment: Have you tried changing `@RequestPart(required = false)` to `@RequestParam("file", required = false)`?

Comment: @PhilipWrage, that was the fix! do you know why this was the issue? does part not get affected by the properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `@RequestPart(required = false)` to `@RequestParam("file", required = false)` before `MultipartFile media` within your `createPost` method's argument list.

I suspect that the `type` extracted from `const { uri, type } = imageURI;` is not `multipart/form-data`, but instead is something like `image/jpeg`.

Despite the fact that your Headers section contains `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`, the part type likely does not correspond, and [`@RequestPart`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html) is unable to find an `HttpMessageConverter` to deal with the larger multi-part files.

The [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation can also be used for `multipart/form-data`, and in your case it appears to be able to find an appropriate `Converter`.

You could use some tool like Fiddler to review the actual data coming from your API call in order to verify my suspicions about the part type.  Alternatively, you could add another argument to your `createPost` method ([`MultipartHttpServletRequest request`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartHttpServletRequest.html)) to gain access to the headers of the individual parts directly from within your Java code.

Answer (score -3):

**For Spring Webflux**

If the port number is wrong, then "413 request entity too large" response can be given by postman, when trying to upload files.

Comment: What do you mean by the port number being wrong? As in typing the wrong port while inputting the URL? Wouldn't that just mean some other process is listening on that port and returning its own 413?