# 413 Request Entity Too Large while uploading a multipart file

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat9

I've the below uploadfile method to upload multipart files and I see 413 Request Entity Too Large while uploading a large size file like 28MB. I've set `maxPostSize` to 50MB in tomcat 9 server configurations and also tried which is suggested in below link. I've added below `spring.servlet` properties in `application.properties` file.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
```

```java
@PostMapping(********)
@ResponseBody
public response uploadfile(
    @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) String id,
    @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile multipartFile,
    @RequestPart(required = true) data data) throws ServicesException {
    return service.uploadfile(id, multipartFile, data);
}
```

I've tried suggestions in below link but still seeing the same error: [Spring Boot Upload Multipart 413 Request Entity Too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57897803/spring-boot-upload-multipart-413-request-entity-too-large)

Comment: Can you also post your stacktrace?

Comment: And which multipartResolver are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Do you use `ngrok` or any proxy?  By default in Spring, you should get:

```json
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.",
```

So I think you should check some firewall configurations, because the issue may lie there.